# Atom is not neutral?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, atoms

The thing that always confused me, was how can atom be electrically neutral, if electrons are closer to observer. Well, okay, I started to read a quantum mechanics book, so to clarify: there is a big probability, that electrons will be closer. First, I imagined electric field as a finite sphere, but then, I understood, that it is infinite respectly to scales, hence, nucleou's and electron's fields canceles each other. But then I again understood, that density decreases with distance, hence the field near electron, and hence atom, should be negative.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the purposes of this discussion, let's think of the atom as a positively-charged point surrounded by a negatively-charged cloud. The total charge of the negatively-charged cloud is equal to the total charge of the positively-charged point. This question can be answered entirely within the realm of classical electromagnetism.

An atom looks the same from every direction; we say that it has spherical symmetry. Because of this, the electric field should *also* look the same from every direction. This pretty strictly restricts the behavior of the electric field; because of this symmetry, the electric field can *only* depend on the distance from the atom, and it can only point either directly toward or directly away from the atom. Therefore, the electric field should look the *same* at every point on a sphere centered on the atom.

This fact is important because of a particular fact of electromagnetism: Gauss's Law, which says that the total electric field poking through a surface is dependent only on the *total charge* contained by that surface. Let's choose any sphere with a radius larger than the radius of the atom. The total charge contained in this sphere is zero (the positive and negative charges are the same magnitude, as we said in the beginning). This means that the net electric field poking through the surface is also zero. Ordinarily, this wouldn't tell us much; after all, there are lots of ways for an arbitrary electric field to have a net flux (amount poking through a surface) of zero; for example, half of the surface could have the electric field pointing outward and half could have the electric field pointing inward at the same magnitude. But we don't *have* an arbitrary electric field; our electric field is limited by the symmetry we talked about. It *must* look the same at every point on this sphere, and, as part of this, it must either point outwards everywhere or point inwards everywhere on the sphere. The only way to have zero net flux under these conditions is for the electric field to be *zero* everywhere on the sphere. Since the radius of the sphere didn't matter at all in these calculations, the electric field is zero at a sphere of any radius larger than the radius of the atom; therefore, the electric field is zero *everywhere outside the atom*. This type of argument is called an "argument by symmetry," and it occurs quite often in physics.

Intuitively, you can justify this by noting that, although part of the electron cloud is closer to an observer than the nucleus of the atom, there is also part of the electron cloud that is *further away* from the observer than the nucleus. It turns out that these two effects cancel. If your objection is that the electron is a point particle and can't be in two places at once, this is where quantum mechanics becomes important. In quantum mechanics, the electron is not a point particle; rather, it exists as a distribution over space. The "electron cloud" analogy is not perfect (for example, it does not imply that the electron's probability distribution maps directly to a charge distribution), but the arguments from symmetry still apply. We know that there's an electron somewhere in the atom, and we know that the atom is observed to be spherically symmetric, and that's all we need to complete the argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is a property of the $1/r^2$ force law that charges display that any spherically symmetric charge density will appear to an outside observer as if all of that charge were located at a point in the center. If the density is “hollow” (zero from the center until some radius) so that there are also "inside observers" possible, it turns out that for them the force cancels out completely. You can use superposition to work out any other spherically symmetric charge distribution. A classic example is the uniformly charged sphere of total charge $Q$ where if you are inside of one, you can imagine a superposition of the charge at smaller radius and the charge at larger radius. The latter sees you in a hollow and thus exerts no net force on you after it is all added up; the former sphere has volume proportional to $r^3$ hence charge $Q r^3/R^3$ which acts on you as if it is concentrated at the center, so the field inside the sphere is $$E = \frac{kQr}{R^3}\hat r.$$

Many atoms have a spherically symmetric charge distribution for their electrons. This is a strange aspect of quantum mechanics, it allows for particles to be distributed over space. But this means that outside of the atom, when you shrink all of the charge to a point at the center of the sphere, you just get the number of protons minus the number of electrons. If those two are the same number, then you must not feel any force: the protons at the center must be perfectly canceled out by the electrons distributed around the shell.

Of course some atoms get together in other ways, like in the water molecule, the oxygen atom pulls electrons to it more strongly than the hydrogen atoms can hold, and those hydrogen atoms do not lineup on opposite sides, so there is no symmetry to the situation, and we would say that water has a small dipole moment, which is why ionic things like salt dissolve very readily in water, while more electrically neutral things like oil do not.

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify your question by considering [an electric dipole](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dipole.html), which has $0$ overall charge but non-zero field.  On average, in the case of an atom with one positive and one negative charge, there is no reason to think that an electron would be more often on one side of the nucleus rather than the other, and this is certainly true if one thinks of electrons as circulating on orbits in the simplified pictures of the Bohr model.  If you have many electrons on multiple orbits in different planes, that would be even "truer" in this simplified picture.

Moreover, the field of a dipole decreases quite rapidly (along the axis of the dipole like $1/r^3$) so that, qualitatively at least, it's reasonable to consider the field to be $0$ unless you are interested in the field at very short distances or for very short times.